# Weird async behavior that speeds up processes by over 100x

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, benchmarking

I thought I understood asynchronous in JavaScript as I've been working with it for 3-4 years continuously now, but I've been developing an ORM for server-side libraries and I've come across
This weird phenomenon twice now and I just don't seem to understand it.

To understand the whole question, I need to explain the code, but I will also have the link for the code [here](https://github.com/kinshipjs/core).

My ORM has finished its development (for now) and I have been doing some random benchmarking against Drizzle ORM, just to base where it is at.

The ORM follows a flow:

- User creates a new Context which is connected to a single Table

  - Internally, the context calls `DESCRIBE` (or like for whichever adapter the user is using) to get a schema of the table. Since this is an asynchronous task done in a constructor, it is assigned to a class instance promise variable.
- User calls various clause functions to build their command.

  - Internally, each clause method may rely on the schema mentioned previously, or it may just rely on the previously built state, so the clause methods are appended onto the `promise` variable using `.then()`.
- User calls desired transactional function telling my ORM to send the command to the database.

  - This call is asynchronous, and since we are finished preparing a command, all the ORM must do is await the instance `promise` variable.
- The user may wish to `check out` the state of their table context, meaning they can save the state of the command then and create a new table context where its base state is at that point. (e.g., `const acdcTracks = await tracks.where(m => m.Name.equals("AC/DC")).checkout()`)

  - This will also await the promise like it is done in the transactional command methods.

My ORM does a little more than Drizzle where it serializes the results of your queries in the most user-friendly way. Meaning, if you left join with a cross-reference table for a "many-to-many" relationship, the result will be appropriately mapped to be like

```
{ 
  Id: 1, 
  Name: "foo", 
  MyCrossRefTable: [
    { 
      Table1Id: 1, 
      Table2Id: 1, 
      Table2Records: { 
        Id: 1, 
        Name: "Blah" 
      }
    },
    ...
]
```

This is expected to slow down the ORM by quite a bit since it does a lot of nested iteration and recursion to accomplish this.

Here is where the weird part comes in...

If I were to benchmark the program like so:

```js
console.log(`Kinship: Querying (18 playlists left join 8719 playlist_tracks left join 3503 tracks) rows.`);
await runBenchmark(async () => {
    await playlists
        .include(m => m.PlaylistTracks // one to many relationships
            .thenInclude(m => m.Track)) //one-to-one relationship
        .select();
}, /** number of warmup runs */ 10, /** number of real runs */ 10);
```

The results yielded are unsurprising:

```
### WARMUP RUNS ###
    -                Total Runs: 10
    -   First (in milliseconds): 545.378ms
    -    Last (in milliseconds): 501.379ms
    -   Total (in milliseconds): 4684.447ms
    - Average (in milliseconds): 468.444ms
    - Maximum (in milliseconds): 545.378ms
    - Minimum (in milliseconds): 441.483ms
###### REAL #######
    -                Total Runs: 10
    -   First (in milliseconds): 497.99ms
    -    Last (in milliseconds): 431.102ms
    -   Total (in milliseconds): 4502.12ms
    - Average (in milliseconds): 450.201ms
    - Maximum (in milliseconds): 498.497ms
    - Minimum (in milliseconds): 426.147ms
```

But, if I choose to `check out` the state of include (left join),

```js
const ps = await playlists
  .include(m => m.PlaylistTracks
    .thenInclude(m => m.Track)).checkout();
console.log(`Kinship: Querying (18 playlists left join 8719 playlist_tracks left join 3503 tracks) rows.`);
await runBenchmark(async () => {
    await ps
        .select();
}, 10, 1000);
```

the results change DRASTICALLY. (not to be confused with the actual results-- I double-checked the actual results, and they are all the same and correct)

```
Kinship: Querying (18 LJOIN 8719 LJOIN 3503) rows.
### WARMUP RUNS ###
    -                Total Runs: 10
    -   First (in milliseconds): 565.825ms
    -    Last (in milliseconds): 0.625ms
    -   Total (in milliseconds): 571.655ms
    - Average (in milliseconds): 57.165ms
    - Maximum (in milliseconds): 565.825ms
    - Minimum (in milliseconds): 0.531ms
###### REAL #######
    -                Total Runs: 1000
    -   First (in milliseconds): 0.535ms
    -    Last (in milliseconds): 0.468ms
    -   Total (in milliseconds): 534.780ms
    - Average (in milliseconds): 0.534ms
    - Maximum (in milliseconds): 0.825ms
    - Minimum (in milliseconds): 0.353ms
```

Any explanation or help as to why this is behaving the way it is would be amazing.

I know this may not be a perfect explanation of how my code works, but it is the best I could do, as the library is pretty big. I'm just extremely confused about why this works, and I don't want a good feature in my library that I can't explain. I would also like to make it where it is consistent.

Final note:

The serialization is the slow part in the non-checkout benchmark, here are the individual benchmarks for serialization for each of the runs I posted above.

Without checkout:

```js
Execute speed
    -                Total Runs: 20
    -   First (in milliseconds): 36.782ms
    -    Last (in milliseconds): 33.241ms
    -   Total (in milliseconds): 686.282ms
    - Average (in milliseconds): 34.314ms
    - Maximum (in milliseconds): 36.782ms
    - Minimum (in milliseconds): 32.445ms
Serialize speed
    -                Total Runs: 20
    -   First (in milliseconds): 480.52ms
    -    Last (in milliseconds): 397.813ms
    -   Total (in milliseconds): 8470.345ms
    - Average (in milliseconds): 423.517ms
    - Maximum (in milliseconds): 480.52ms
    - Minimum (in milliseconds): 392.408ms
```

With checkout:

```js
Execute speed
    -                Total Runs: 1010
    -   First (in milliseconds): 35.553ms
    -    Last (in milliseconds): 0.450ms
    -   Total (in milliseconds): 552.11ms
    - Average (in milliseconds): 0.546ms
    - Maximum (in milliseconds): 35.553ms
    - Minimum (in milliseconds): 0.337ms
Serialize speed
    -                Total Runs: 1010
    -   First (in milliseconds): 530.35ms
    -    Last (in milliseconds): 0.12ms
    -   Total (in milliseconds): 546.385ms
    - Average (in milliseconds): 0.540ms
    - Maximum (in milliseconds): 530.35ms
    - Minimum (in milliseconds): 0.11ms
```

Comment: I didn't find the source code via the link you included. Anyway, the question should not depend on external content. Can you include the relevant code inside the question?

Comment: What if you just do playlists.checkout().select() inside your runBenchmark vs playlists.checkout() outside and then calling .select() inside your runBenchmark? Like it seems more likely there's something in your include and thenInclude that's not very optimized, rather than "weird async behaviour" :v

Comment: @trincot The code consists of 10 separate files totaling around 3000 to 5000 lines of code, and I can't necessarily split it up to only show relevant information, as a lot of it is relevant. The link may not work because it is in an organization, even though the repo is marked public...

Comment: @JaDa I decided to rerun the code and try that as well. I also decided to look at the results again. It seems that the results weren't actually all appearing as expected due to to a small overlook. Once I fixed it, it became consistent again.

That's not to say this question is solved. I've had this issue before I rewrote this library, and me and my senior developer confirmed that the results were correct then. I just jumped the gun this time thinking it showed up again.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you're talking about. Consistent in what way? As @trincot you really need to give some links to code.

Comment: But your 2 benchmarks are completely different aren't they? In the first case you are measuring how long the whole process to resolve `await playlists.include(m => m.PlaylistTracks.thenInclude(m => m.Track)).select()` took, while in the second case you already did wait for `await playlists.include(m => m.PlaylistTracks.thenInclude(m => m.Track)).checkout();` and area only waiting for `.select()` to resolve in the benchmark. So if the big part of the work is already done when `checkout()` resolves, the second benchmark doesn't have to wait much.

Comment: (not even talking about the fact only a single base `ps` object is created in the second case, which probably also means less memory being used).

Comment: @Kaiido I've changed code and haven't come across the issue since, but the benchmarks did look different, but they were essentially the same. When I awaited the `.checkout()` portion, it was only awaiting the startup sequence (e.g., describing the table and any relating table from the database). It also doesn't make a difference because my benchmark had 10 warm up runs, which means either way, the real tracked time should have been roughly the same in either scenario. The second scenario should be a little faster, but not magnitudes more.